# Scripted pipeline - Groovy syntax to grab commit hash or tag

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

For Dev/QA/Prod pipeline, we want to notify users, which commit hash is being picked by the pipeline.

Mainly this helps in Prod pipeline, before deploying in production.

Below is the groovy syntax used to pick latest commit from a specific branch.

```
git branch: branchName, credentialsId: credential, url: "${gitLabServer}/${projectName}/${repo}.git"
```

---

1)
How to grab the commit hash/tag from checkout?

2) 
How to grab the error, if specific branch is not available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get info using return `TreeMap` from `git`:

```
try {
    d = git(branch: branchName, credentialsId: credential, url: "${gitLabServer}/${projectName}/${repo}.git")
    echo d["GIT_COMMIT"]
} catch (Exception e) {
    echo "${e}"
}
```

Fields:

```
GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL 
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME 
GIT_BRANCH 
GIT_COMMIT
GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL 
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME 
GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH 
GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT
GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT
GIT_URL
```

Update:

```
def treeMapData
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage ('Get Commit') {
            steps{
                script{
                    try {
                        treeMapData = git(branch: branchName, credentialsId: credential, url: "${gitLabServer}/${projectName}/${repo}.git")
                        echo treeMapData["GIT_COMMIT"]
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        echo "${e}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
def treeMapData
node {
    stage ('Build') {
        try {
            treeMapData = git(branch: branchName, credentialsId: credential, url: "${gitLabServer}/${projectName}/${repo}.git")
            echo treeMapData["GIT_COMMIT"]
        } catch (Exception e) {
            echo "${e}"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the `branchname` does not exist?

Comment: @overexchange what do you mean `branchname` not exist? If `branchname` not exist you will get error: `ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job`.

Comment: yes, I get that error on `stdout`/`stderr`, but I need to grab that error, in a return value

Comment: @overexchange check my answer update, I added `try/catch` block.

Comment: Init `def treeMapData` variable outside pipeline

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188898/discussion-between-sers-and-overexchange).